# NET 5.0 - serilog-sinks-file not creating logs

Tags: serilog, asp.net-core-5.0

Since I updated my code to .NET 5.0 and used a newer version of serilog, I cannot get any rolling file anymore

I tried debugging serilog , it creates a debug file but nothing is in there

```
private static void CreateLogger()
{
    // Init Serilog configuration
    var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.logs.json")
        .Build();

    Log.Logger = new Serilog.LoggerConfiguration().ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
        .Enrich.WithProperty("Application", GetAssemblyProductName())
        .CreateLogger();

    var file = File.CreateText(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"serilog.txt");
    Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.Enable(TextWriter.Synchronized(file));

    Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.Enable(msg => Debug.WriteLine(msg));
    Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.Enable(Console.Error);
}
```

here is my appsetings.log.json

```
{
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [
      "Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights"
    ],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "System": "Warning",
        "System.Net.Http.HttpClient": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Async",
        "Args": {
          "configure": [
            {
              "Name": "File",
              "Args": {
                "pathFormat": "logs.txt",
                "formatter": "Serilog.Formatting.Compact.CompactJsonFormatter, Serilog.Formatting.Compact",
                "outputTemplate": "({SourceContext}) {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}",
                "rollingInterval": "Day",
                "fileSizeLimitBytes": 50000000,
                "rollOnFileSizeLimit": true,
                "retainedFileCountLimit": 15,
                "buffered": true
              }
            },
            {
              "Name": "ApplicationInsights",
              "Args": {
                "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Information",
                "outputTemplate": "({SourceContext}) ({Application}/{MachineName}/{ThreadId}) {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}",
                "telemetryConverter": "Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights.Sinks.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryConverters.TraceTelemetryConverter, Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithThreadId" ],
    "Properties": {
      "Application": "myapp"
    }
  }
}
```

am I missing something ?

thanks for helping me on this

Answer (score 1):

Please someone correct me if this is wrong but I assumed you need to list the sinks you wanted to run in the Using section - therefore adding the File sink to your appsettings should fix this - as per below:

```
"Serilog": {
  "Using": [
    "Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights","Serilog.Sinks.File"
  ],
```